# How to extract a string value from an array using scripted field in kibana?

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch-painless

Is there a way to extract a `string` value from an `array` with the use of `if statement` in scripted field in `kibana`. I tried the below code, however, I am unable to filter out the correct and incorrect values in discover tab of `kibana`. This might be due to remark field is an `array`.

```
def result_string = "";

if (doc['nac.keyword'].value =="existing_intent" &&doc['remark.keyword'].value != "acceptable") {
            result_string = "incorrect";
        } 
        
if (doc['nac.keyword'].value =="existing_intent" &&doc['remark.keyword'].value == "acceptable") {
            result_string = "correct";
        } 
return result_string;`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the contains method defined on Array to check for element membership:

```
!doc['remark.keyword'].value.contains("acceptable") //does not contain
```

For this, you might want to ensure first that `doc['remark.keyword'].value` is indeed an Array.